# I cant join two tables with Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

this is what I got:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select()->where('a.id = ?0')->setParameters(array($id));
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationUser',    'b');
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationContact', 'c');
```

this wont work, I get: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 97: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN' error message. But if I try to do them one-by-one

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select()->where('a.id = ?0')->setParameters(array($id));
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationContact', 'c');
```

or

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select()->where('a.id = ?0')->setParameters(array($id));
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationUser',    'b');
```

it does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$queryBuilder->leftJoin('a.**nameOfPropertyInAEntity**',    'b');

Comment: interestind why I needed once "Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationUser" and then "AccommodationUser"

Comment: If it's inside an entity repository you don't need to specify `from` because it's a shortcut to 'select($alias)->from($entityName)` - if you called `createQueryBuilder` directly on the entity manager you need to specify which entity to select from.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine doesn't use the classnames in join statements. If you want to join another table you need to use the form `alias.property`

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('u')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u', 'phonenumbers', 'p', 'u.id = p.user_id')
```

Source: [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses%20Doctrine%20Docs)